# How to make left Ctrl as Super on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Is there a way to map the <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> as <kbd>Super</kbd> on Ubuntu 12.10.

The keyboard layout app doesn't seem to have this option.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind-of an ugly hack, but it should work:

1. Go to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` (this is where I find keyboard layout files on Ubuntu 12.04, but I suppose 12.10 should be similar),
2. Find your layout file (I guess for United States keyboard it will be simply `us`),
3. Add this line there: `key <LCTL> { [ Super_L  ] };` (I think it can go right to the first "section" of that file),
4. Logout and login again.